# Avoid orphan title followed by list

Tags: css, printing

I have an `<h2>` title that introduce an `<ol>` list as follow:

```
<h2>A title</h2>
<ol>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br />consectetur adipisicing elit, sed<br />do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut<br />labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud ...</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br />consectetur adipisicing elit, sed<br />do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut<br />labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud ...</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br />consectetur adipisicing elit, sed<br />do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut<br />labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud ...</li>
</ol>
```

This pattern (title+list) is repeated a number of times and I have issues when printing because the title is sometimes separated from it's following list.

As an illustration of the problem: [this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q78vg/1/) gets printed as follows:

```
[...]
 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud ...

Some title

================================================================================

 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud ...
[...]
```

I've unsuccessfully tried to avoid page breaks after `<h2>` and before `<ol>`:

```
h2 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
ol {
    page-break-before: avoid;
}
```

Comment: So basically, you want it so that the `h2` is always together with the `ol`?

Comment: Yes exactly: at least with the first `li` of `ol`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by defining a CSS class called "page-break" which has the rule `page-break-before: always !important` and I applied it to the `<h2>` where the screwed up page break was occurring.

```
<h2 class="page-break">Some title</h2>

<style>
    @media print {  
        p.padding {
            margin-bottom: 9cm;
        }
        ol li {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
        h2 {
            page-break-after: avoid;
        }
        ol {
            page-break-before: avoid;
        }

        .page-break {
            page-break-before: always !important;   
        }
    }
</style>
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

This might be able to be combined with the CSS `:nth-of-type` selector if you're looking to force a page break every three or four `<h2>`s .

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL8ryg07/).